# The fourth power of any integer has the form $8m$ or 8m + 1 for some integer m.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

In my textbook I came across this problem:

> Prove that the fourth power of any integer has the form $8m$ or $8m + 1$ for some integer $m$.

I know how to solve the algebra but don't understand the reasoning behind some steps of the proof.

Here is my Proof:

> Suppose $n$ is an integer. By the quotient remainder theorem with $d=4$, $n$ can be written in four forms $4q$, $4q+1$, $4q+2$, or $4q+3$ for some integer $q$. 
> **Case $1$ $(n=4q) $:**
> Then, $n^4=(4q)^4=256q^4=8(32q^4)$
> Let $32q^4=m$. Note that $m$ is an integer since it’s the product of other integers. Hence, $n^4=8m$ for some integer $m$.
> **Case $2$ $(n=4q+1)$:**
> Then, $n^4=(4q+1)^4=256q^4+256q^3+96q^2+16q+1=8(32q^4+32q^3+12q^2+2q)+1$.
> Let, $32q^4+32q^3+12q^2+2q=m$. Note that $m$ is an integer since it’s the product and sum of other integers. Hence, $n^4=8m+1$ for some integer $m$.
> **Cases 3 (n=4q+2):**
> Then, $n^4=(4q+2)^4=256q^4+512q^3+384q^2+128q+16=8(32q^4+64^3+48^2+16q+2)$
> Let $32q^4+64^3+48^2+16q+2=m$. Note that $m$ is an integer since it’s the product and sum of other integers. Hence, $n^4=8m$ for some integer $m$.
> **Cases 4 (n=4q+3):**
> Then, $n^4=(4q+3)^4=256q^4+768q^3+864q^2+432q+81=8(32q^4+96q^3+108q^2+54q+10)+1$
> Let $32q^4+96q^3+108q^2+54q+10=m$. Note that $m$ is an integer since it’s the product and sum of other integers. Hence, $n^4=8m+1$ for some integer $m$.
> Thus, For all integers $n$, $n^4=8m$ or $n^4=8m+1$ for some integer $m$.

So, i have two main problems: 
**1- should i use the quotient remainder theorem?**
I searched google and found that the parity property can be used instead:[image] 
**2- How to know whether to use the quotient remainder theorem or the parity property in proof?**

Comment: There are often many different ways of proving a theorem and it is sometimes hard to say which is best. In this example, the second proof is shorter and involves easier algebra, but that doesn't mean the first proof is wrong.

Comment: The parity theorem is the same as the quotient/remainder theorem with a different dividend, so there isn't much difference between the two approaches. The second seems more elegant because it has fewer cases, but it's not more correct.

Comment: so, if one approach takes less cases that becomes the best one to use? also, can there be problems where one approach is the correct one? and in that case how to know which one to use?

Comment: Any argument that correctly reaches the desired conclusion is a correct argument. There can indeed be cases where there are two possible methods but only one of them is correct, or two correct methods that solve a particular problem but only one of them works for a more general version of the problem. But you can never say one method is more correct than another if both prove the theorem.

Comment: thanks for the help.